# Specifics of Objective-C runtime performance penalties

Tags: objective-c, c, performance

I've been experimenting with using Objective-C (specifically the GNU runtime, I'm not using GNUStep or anything like that) to extend C with objects.  So far its going well - it works well and I really like the syntax, however from what I've been reading there is a performance penalty to using Objective-C objects.

I'm not normally one to optimise prematurely but I'm developing a game and so performance will eventually end up being fairly critical - I'd like to know what I'm getting myself into!  Several people have suggested that I will be fine using Objective-C in a game as long as my innermost loops are written in standard C, however the question is finding the point where I should make that switch.

So my question is twofold:

- What exactly will incur a performance penalty? *(so I know what I should avoid)*
- **Roughly** how significant is this performance penalty? *(so I can guestimate in advance which bits of my game will need to be written in C anyway)*

My guess is that calling methods on an Objective-C object will incurr a penalty, but I wasn't sure what else would - does de-referencing an Objective-C object incurr a similar penalty?

```
int a = myobj->a;
```

How about using a `try-catch-finally` - will this incur a performance penalty in situations where there is no exception thrown?

I realise that to a certain extent I could figure most of this out myself using benchmarks, but I'm relatively new to this and I was hoping for a deeper understanting of how Objective-C works and the nature of any performance penalties.

I'm not interested in C++ for the moment, I'm just experimenting with Objective-C.

Comment: There’s another Stack Overflow question about the overhead in invoking Objective-C methods. That question links to two good blog posts about message dispatch — one by bbum, and the other one by Mike Ash: [iOS: What is the processing overhead in invoking an Objective-C method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700065/ios-what-is-the-processing-overhead-in-invoking-an-objective-c-method).

Comment: Mike Ash has another post comparing the performance of IMP-based calls, C++ virtual method calls, Objective-C message send and other operations: [Performance Comparisons of Common Operations, Leopard Edition](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is twofold:
>
> What exactly will incur a performance penalty? (so I know what I should avoid)
>
> Roughly how significant is this performance penalty? (so I can guestimate in advance which bits of my game will need to be written in C anyway)

(my basis from apple's implementations:)

in most cases, the biggest penalty is that every instance method (messaging) is a dynamic call

the cost of this call/message is approximately 4x as costly as a c++ virtual call.

these calls may not be optimized out (unless somebody makes a good implementation to JIT/HotSpot), and the methods, unlike c or c++, may not be inlined.

but there's more than messaging:

your objects will be ref-counted allocations. this means: lots of locking and many individual, small allocations, plus atomics for the ref counting.

objc_msgSend and variants (the meat of the runtime messaging implementation) can take, like 10% of the execution time alone (extreme real world cases).

it can add to the binary size as well.

idiomatic uses push it further from the speed of c++ or c in many areas. (e.g. consider how numbers are passed/handled).

how much it costs you depends on the size of your methods. good ood means your methods will typically be short. you'll either end up with a lot of messages and noticable weight (if it is to be high performance), or compromising your designs.

there are a few other gotchas, like in realtime apps.

> int a = myobj->a;

no diff compared to c

> ...exceptions...

(iirc) apple's previous exception model used to use costly setup, now they are along the lines of c++'s zero cost exceptions (optimized that exceptions will not be regularly thrown, and marginal on entry/setup, but expensive to throw/catch).

if performance is really important, i'd avoid it and just go with c++. it has plenty of features and speed. you'd have a little work to do to get some of the conveniences of objc -- most of that lies in the libraries available, not the language.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would code up a prototype, give it a realistic work load, and then find out which parts of it were problems.
[Here's an example of what I mean.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)

In other words, you could get answers telling you that such-and-so is "efficient" or "inefficient", but whether it actually applies in your case is a total WAG.
So the thing to do is try it, and let the program itself tell you which parts need something better.